# How could I transfer binary data using a computer display in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, binary

I apologise if this question is of two wide a field of consideration.

I want to transfer binary data using the graphical display of a computer. I could imagine converting segments of the data into a graphical form such as a QR code or, more simply, visual flashes. These visual signals could be translated back into binary data using perhaps the image histogram functionality OpenCV on a video recording of these visual signals.

So, a first step could be to convert the binary data (say, an image file) to a base 2 representation. A binary file can be converted to an ASCII base 64 representation in a way such as the following:

```
base64 piglet_squid.jpg > piglet_squid.txt
```

I am not sure how to convert the binary file to a base 2 representation.

Anyway, would anyone have ideas about how to implement this silly idea?

Comment: First of all, a binary file is by definition already in a base 2 representation. I think you need to define at least why you're trying to do this, and what characteristics you need this system to have, then probably ask the question on one of the more specialised sites that would deal with comms, just to figure out what you want to do. Once you know, try to do it, then come back here with specific questions about sub problems you're stuck on.

Comment: QR code seems a reasonable solution. depending on wether the communication is bidirectional or unidirectional, you may be able to achieve maximum transfer speeds, or you may have to figure out what is the maximum symbol transfer rate

Comment: @Marcin I'm not quite sure what the right words are here. I'm talking about representing the data in such a form that it could be encoded as on/off flashes of light. So, rather than a sort of bytestream representation, I'd want actual 0s and 1s stored in an ASCII text file, if that makes any sense. I'm asking for guidance in this regard.

Comment: Then change your question to be specifically about that.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for your suggestion. I actually did that first [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990034/how-can-i-convert-a-binary-file-to-a-base-2-representation-in-linux), but I think people may not have been clear about what I wanted to achieve overall. That's why I ask the question in the form I do now. It makes it a bit clearer that I want the binary form to be something very much *on* and *off*.

Answer (score 0):

With python, `io.open(file, mode='rb')` will give a byte stream. To convert each byte to a number, you'll need `ord` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) which will give you an integer in the range 0-256. You can then use `%` to detect if the current bit is a 1 or 0, and `>>` to shift down. In fact, you could code that as a reduction if you wanted.

Try something like this:

```
def binariser(filename):
    input =  io.open(filename, mode='rb')
    for c in input.read():
        intval = ord(c)
        for shift in xrange(8):
            yield (intval >> shift) % 2
```